Extremely slow boot times on PopOS 22.04
I was dual booting Bazzite (Fedora Atomic) and PopOS on my laptop and would always get to each of the login screens in seconds. Never actually checked it, but I'm sure it was like 5-10s. Today after deleting the Bazzite partitions (as the one game I play started crashing there for some reason), the time to login screen was alarmingly slow.
das@pop-os:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 4.479s (firmware) + 672ms (loader) + 9.313s (kernel) + 1min 34.944s (userspace) = 1min 49.410s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 34.932s in userspace

Below are some more details I have seen people in similar situations provide. snapd appears to have something to do with it.
das@pop-os:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 34.932s
└─multi-user.target @1min 34.932s
  └─virtualbox.service @1min 34.858s +73ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 34.841s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 30.773s +4.068s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.695s +73ms
          └─basic.target @1min 30.668s
            └─dbus-broker.service @1min 30.608s +56ms
              └─dbus.socket @1min 30.588s
                └─sysinit.target @1min 30.580s
                  └─snapd.apparmor.service @1.254s +75ms
                    └─apparmor.service @1.157s +79ms
                      └─local-fs.target @1.086s
                        └─run-snapd-ns-cups.mnt.mount @1min 31.179s
                          └─run-snapd-ns.mount @1min 31.077s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @530ms
                              └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @515ms +15ms
                                └─systemd-sysusers.service @497ms +16ms
                                  └─systemd-remount-fs.service @469ms +26ms
                                    └─systemd-journald.socket @439ms
                                      └─-.mount @422ms
                                        └─-.slice @422ms

das@pop-os:~$ snap version
snap    2.65.3+22.04
snapd   2.65.3+22.04
series  16
pop     22.04
kernel  6.9.3-76060903-generic

das@pop-os:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0  74.2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1621
loop2         7:2    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/1663
loop3         7:3    0  67.8M  1 loop /snap/cups/1058
loop4         7:4    0  67.8M  1 loop /snap/cups/1067
loop5         7:5    0 505.1M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop6         7:6    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop7         7:7    0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
loop8         7:8    0  44.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/22991
zram0       251:0    0   7.6G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  1022M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     4G  0 part /recovery
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 460.8G  0 part /

dmesg output
